# Dynamically recording the total height of the component loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to record dynamically the total height of the table while it is created/rendered. The problem is when you set up useEffect and useCallback hooks, the render loop never ends.

When you use an empty dependency array in Column's useEffect, the values are zero.

```
const text = " " //some long text

const CustomTd: FC<IColumn> = ({ reportHeight, line }) => {
  const [lineRef, { height: lineHeight }] = useElementSize(); //usehooks-ts

  useEffect(() => {
    reportHeight(lineHeight);
  }, [reportHeight, lineHeight]);

  return <Td ref={lineRef}>{line}</Td>;
};

const CustomTable: FC = () => {
  const [totalHeight, setTotalHeight] = useState(0);
  const [currentHeight, setCurrentHeight] = useState(0);

  const reportHeight = useCallback(
    (height: number) => {
      setTotalHeight((prevTotalHeight) => prevTotalHeight + height);
      setCurrentHeight(height);
    },
    [totalHeight]
  );

  return (
    <Table>
      {text.split(" ").map((word) => (
        <Tr>
          <CustomTd line={word} reportHeight={reportHeight} />
          <Td>{currentHeight}</Td>
          <Td>{totalHeight}</Td>
        </Tr>
      ))}
      ;
    </Table>
  );
};
```

See codesandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/record-element-height-w1bb3u

Comment: Please provide a [mre] in the question itself. Having a codesandbox is nice as supporting information, but questions must be self-contained.